# DiscordAPIError: Cannot edit a message authored by another user

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am trying to create a "coinflip" command. Everything worked how it is supposed to, but one simple thing.

I want it to write "Flipping coin..." and three seconds later edit the message with the result.

I set that up. But each time it tries to execute the code where it edits the message it gives me this error:

```
"DiscordAPIError: Cannot edit a message authored by another user".
```

All the relevant code:

```js
message.channel.send("Flipping coin...").then(
    setTimeout(() => {
        message.edit(`Heads! You won ${amountOfChange} GP! [Total balance: ${data[msgSenderID].bal}]`);
    }, 2000)
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is pretty self-explanatory, you are trying to edit the message of the user that ran the command.

[`TextChannel#send`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=send) returns a [`Message`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message) that needs to be passed as an argument to the arrow function.

```
param => expression
```

---

```js
message.channel.send('Flipping coin...').then(coinFlipMessage => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        coinFlipMessage.edit(`Heads! You won ${amountOfChange} GP! [Total balance: ${data[msgSenderID].bal}]`)
    }, 3000)
})
```

Comment: The code above would work, but I strongly suggest you not name the `Message` that it returns to message, as it can be confusing with the message of the user that ran the command.